# Can't find NewViewController subclass in Storyboard view

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I want to change a `TableViewController` to a new `UIViewController` (PlayersViewController) from a `UIViewController` subclass, so I added two files (.h, .m), and then went back to the Identity Inspector/Custom Class.

Expected to find the `PlayersViewController` in the pulldown menu in Custom Class but could not find it, so I typed it in and hit "Return", but that didn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new class should inherit from UITableViewController, not UIViewController. Only subclasses of the base class are available to select in the custom class field.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. Learned something new today! Thanks again!